How to pull DIAGSESSION/ETW/ETL file from Azure into Pipeline
For context, I have API's that are hosted/monitored on Azure and have the profiler enabled.
I was wondering if it was possible to get a DIAGSESSION/ETW/ETL file from application insights profiler and automate it after executing a test via pipeline and collecting the profiling data that for example has the most highest errors, response times ,etc? How would I go about doing this?
I would want it to access and the download the file on an agent/VM and so I'm not sure if I could pull in the information without having to go to the browser and logging in and downloading.
I plan to make a powershell script that takes this file and generates specific graphs for me on perfview/WPA

Not sure if this is what you need, but you can use Azure CLI to query a log analytics workspace or execute a query on app insights

@RuiJarimba this is still awesome to use! Let's me query specific things that I need, but I was specifically looking to download the stack trace that comes from the azure profiler (DIAGSESSION file that contains the etw/etl/xml etc) onto my VM/agent machine.

Unfortunately, the files you're looking for stay local to the machine.
If the application is configured for App Insights, the telemetry data is transmitted in real time.
Once in App Insights, it must be queried using Kusto Query Language (KQL).
So, it is possible to retrieve the data programmatically, from the Application Insights API using a token, but you must determine the correct queries to retrieve your desired data.
To access the API programmatically, or in script, you'll need to create or use an existing service principal for authentication. There are many articles on how to do this.
Here's a simple example of a call you may make, using PowerShell, to execute a simple query:
# Install Az module if not installed
if (-not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Az)) {
    Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Force -SkipPublisherCheck
}

# Login to Azure using service principal credentials
$tenantId = "yourAzureTenantId"
$clientId = "yourServicePrincipalClientId"
$clientSecret = "yourServicePrincipalClientSecret"

$secureClientSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName PSCredential -ArgumentList $clientId, $secureClientSecret

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -Tenant $tenantId

# Variables
$appInsightsAppId = "yourApplicationInsightsAppId"
$resourceGroupName = "yourResourceGroupName"
$appName = "yourAppName"

# Acquire Azure AD token
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://api.applicationinsights.io/").Token
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
}
# Example query
$kustoQuery = "requests | where timestamp > ago(24h) | project session_Id, operation_Id | top 1"

$queryUrl = "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/$appInsightsAppId/query?query=$kustoQuery"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $queryUrl -Headers $headers -Method Get

# Get data in API response body (json)
$sessionId = $response.value[0].session_Id
$operationId = $response.value[0].operation_Id


this is good to know! So, I wouldn't be able to download the stack trace that I usually could download manually on the browser through app insight? I can see myself utilizing the KQL for specific requests, but what I essentially went is the Hot Path that the profiler provides or does KQL offer that ability as long as I query properly?

Also, would the KQL give me ETL/ETW raw data that I could use to add onto WPA?

Let me get back to you on your first comment. I need to check whether the API is doing file generation, or whether the Portal Web Service or another intermediary service is. KQL won't give files.

Thanks! Super appreciated. This would be a big help.
